# Temporal Graph Databases for event based data

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, temporal-database

I have data coming in telling me that an event has happened for a specific things.

Example:

- Box #1 is at location A at 2015-02-15 10:00.
- Box #1 has been put inside Box #2 at 2015-02-15 10:15.
- Box #2 has been put inside Box #3 at 2015-02-15 11:00.
- Box #3 is at location B at 2015-02-16 03:00.
- Box #2 has been removed from Box #3 at 2015-02-16 04:30.
- Box #3 is at location C at 2015-02-16 05:00.

I have three main requirements:

1. I should be able to tell where all my boxes are as of querying right now.
   e.g. Querying at 2015-02-16 06:00 should result in. Box #1 is inside Box #2 at location B. Box #3 is at location C and has nothing inside it.
2. I should be able to see everything that happened to a specific box.
   e.g. For Box #1:

   - Was at Location A at 2015-02-15 10:00
   - Was put inside Box #2 at 2015-02-15 10:15
   - Was inside Box #2, which was put inside Box #3 at 2015-02-15 11:00
   - Was inside Box #2, which was in Box #3 which was at location B at 2015-02-16 03:00.
   - Was inside Box #2 which was removed from Box #3 at 2015-02-16 04:30.
3. I should be able to tell where all the boxes are at a specific time.
   e.g. At 2015-02-16 10:30, Box #1 was inside Box #2 at location A.

I've been looking at graph databases as they appear to handle this type of relationship better than a relational database (trying to do a recursive query in Sql is not easy).
It looks like I would need a Box node, a Location node and edges between them for the relationships "Inside" and "At".
But I'm not sure how I would incorporate the temporal requirement in the graph model.
I've looked at [this](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?608bf0701e3306a23e77) but I'm not sure how to make it work with my requirements.

Also please note: This would have to scale up to 1-4 billion boxes, with each box having anywhere from 1 to 5000 events.
And be able to handle thousands of events coming in second

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem

Here is some sample data crafted adter your example. This is one possible implementation of your problem.

```
// create the boxes and the locations and add relationships
// between them. On each relationship add a time.
create (b1:Box {name: 'Box #1'}) 
create (b2:Box {name: 'Box #2'}) 
create (b3:Box {name: 'Box #3'}) 
create (lA:Location {name: 'A'})
create (lB:Location {name: 'B'})
create (lC:Location {name: 'C'})
create b1-[:AT {time: '2015-02-15 10:00'}]->lA
create b1-[:INSIDE {time: '2015-02-15 10:15'}]->b2
create b2-[:INSIDE {time: '2015-02-15 11:00'}]->b3
create b3-[:AT {time: '2015-02-16 03:00'}]->lB
create b2-[:REMOVED {time: '2015-02-16 04:30'}]->b3
create b3-[:AT {time: '2015-02-16 05:00'}]->lC
return *
```

[image: Picture of the sample graph]

Here is a query to interrogate the graph starting with a specific box. The overall strategy was to pull back the directed chain of boxes.  In this example I simply took the longest chain.  It would be more complete probably to return every path, order them by time and select the path with the latest time.

Once I had the path, i removed the nodes from it and iterated over them and matched the locations and paths.  I pulled the relationship type and the time back for each.

```
match p=(b:Box {name: 'Box #1'})-[:INSIDE|REMOVED*]->(:Box)
with p
order by length(p) desc
limit 1
with nodes(p) as boxes
unwind boxes as box
optional match box-[rel:AT|INSIDE|REMOVED]->(box_spot)
return rel.time as Time
, box.name as Box
, type(rel) as Directive
, box_spot.name as Spot
order by rel.time
```

This could definitely be improved and enhanced with more use cases. The model would not be very good for querying the model by times.  The times are strings on the relationships. A this time neo4j does not allow for indexing of properties on relationships. I think the model works pretty well though for picking a box and following it to an end.

[image]